# Open IE always Kiosk Mode

Tags: internet-explorer

Good morning,

as specified in the object title, I need each page of IE to be open in Kiosk Mode, without forcing any link with -k.

Can you help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the policy, it should work:

Open the Group Policy Editor  (Windows Key + R and type gpedit.msc)

Go to:

```
 Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Internet Explorer
```

Go to the entry to enforce full-screen mode and double-click it

Set it to Enabled